# Create checkboxes in Google Form Questionnaire from Google Spreadsheet Data

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I've seen a million things that are similar, but nothing that is ***actually*** helpful on this.

I have a Google Sheet with about 900 records. I want to create a Google Form that can import that data and create a checkbox in the Google Form for each GS record. I know App Scripts can do a lot of cool things from researching this, but I haven't found anything close to helpful on making this work.

Has anyone imported GS data to a Google Forms to create checkboxes for GS records?

Comment: Did the below answer from @Aaron Dunigan AtLee not answer your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like your question has two parts:

### 1. How to get data from a spreadsheet?

Use the `.getValues()` method of the [Range class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues()) to get spreadsheet data.  It would help to know more about the structure of your spreadsheet, but assuming you have a sheet called "Options" and the data you want is in the range `A1:A10` of that sheet, you can do this:

```
// Get question data from the sheet
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Options')
var choices = sheet.getRange("A1:A10").getValues()
  // .getValues() returns a rectangular array, so we want the first (only) value in each row.
  .map(function(row){return row[0]})
```

Now you have an array of data in `choices`.

### 2. How to add this data to a Form's checkbox item?

I'm assuming you want to [create a new form](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-app#createtitle) with this checkbox question.  If instead you want to insert the question in an existing form, use `FormApp.openById()` or `FormApp.openByUrl()` instead of `FormApp.create()`

```
// Create the form and add the question item
var form = FormApp.create("{Form Title}")
var item = form.addCheckboxItem()
  .setTitle("{Question Title}")
  .setChoiceValues(choices)
```

See the documentation for [`.addCheckBoxItem()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form#addCheckboxItem()) and [`.setChoiceValues()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/checkbox-item#setchoicevaluesvalues)

Comment: Thanks Aaron! This is what I was looking for

Comment: Glad it helped!